# how to deserialize a json list to java object with jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Trying to map a JSON String to java class, but its not working. using jackson library and here is my codes. 
input json:

```
{
   "code":"1",
   "message":"1",
   "result":[
      {
         "serviceid":"13",
         "servicename":"service1",
         "price":"78000",
         "amount":"2048"
      },
      {
         "serviceid":"14",
         "servicename":"service2",
         "price":"118000",
         "amount":"3072"
      }
   ]
}
```

java classes :

```
public class serviceList
{
    public int serviceid;
    public String servicename;
    public double price;
    public int amount;
}

public class serviceList_result
{
    public String code;
    public String message;
    public ArrayList<serviceList> result;

    public serviceList_result()
    {
        result = new ArrayList<serviceList>();
    }

}
```

i am using this code for mappling

```
serviceList_result srv= mapper.readValue(jsonInString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,serviceList_result.class));
```

error :

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT

whats wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for this in your code:

```
serviceList_result srv= mapper.readValue(jsonInString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,serviceList_result.class));
```

With this you are saying that you want to deserialize collection ie `[ ... ]`.

Instead, simply do:

```
serviceList_result srv= mapper.readValue(json, serviceList_result.class);
```

The jackson library will figure out how to create `serviceList_result` object from the class definition.